# Literal translation of Desdemona's Willow-Song (by Rossini): Assisa a un piè d'un salice

Tags: translation

I am looking for a literal translation of the following:

> Assisa a' piè d'un salice,  
>  
>   immersa nel dolore,  
>   gemea traffita Isaura 
>   dal più crudele amore:  
>   L'aura tra i rami flebile  
>   ne ripetva il suon.
>
> I ruscelletti limpidi  
>   a' caldi suoi sospiri,  
>   il mormorio mesceano 
>   de' lor diversi giri:  
>   L'aura fra i rami flebile  
>   ne ripetva il suon.
>
> Salce d'amor delzia!  
>   Ombra pietosa appresta,  
>   di mie sciagure immemore,  
>   all'urna mia funesta;  
>   nè più ripeta l'aura 
>   de' miei lamenti il suon.

So far I found: 
Seated at a foot of a willow,
immersed in grief,
complained the hapless Isaura,
about the most cruel love;
the breeze amid the mournful boughs
repeated the sound.

The lucid rills mixed
her burning sighs 
with the murmur of its passing ways.
The breeze amid the mournful boughs
repeated the sound.

Willow of love's joy 
??? merciful shadow
of my misfortune ???
at my sad urn,
??? the breeze repeats
the sound of my laments.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Stehanie!

Comment: Do you want to translate it to understand the meaning of this aria?

Comment: I am not an opera expert (@DenisNardin, where art thou?), but this lines are not by Rossini, but by *Otello*'s librettist, who should be Francesco Maria Berio di Salsa.

Comment: @DaG I'm here, but I fear I'm not enough of an expert to know all of Rossini's librettists :). A cursory search on the internet seems to confirm what you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my best shot at the translation (do we do translations here? I'm not sure. Feel free to delete this answer if it is off-topic). It is as literal as I am able to make it without completely slaughtering English grammar.

> Seated at the feet of a willow 
>   immersed in grief
>   Isaura moaned, pierced
>   by the most cruel love:
>   the air among the branches weakly
>   repeated their sound
>
> The clean creeks
>   to her warm sighs
>   mixed the murmur
>   of their different turns:
>   the air among the branches weakly
>   repeated their sound
>
> O Willow delight of love!
>   Prepare a merciful shadow,
>   that does not remember my misfortunes,
>   for my unfortunate urn
>   And let the air no more
>   repeat the sound of my laments